# How to use pdf.js with Meteor?

Tags: meteor, pdf.js

I've been trying to get the helloworld example for pdf.js to run in Meteor. So far I have:

- Placed index.html, hello.js, and pdf.js under the "clients" directory
- Enclosed the contents of "hello.js" in a "Meteor.startup()" block
- Stripped out almost everything from index.html:

  ```
  <body>
      <canvas id="the-canvas" style="border:1px solid black;"/>
  </body>
  ```

I thought this was enough to have the example working, but Meteor ends up complaining about the "!DOCTYPE html" declaration in pdf.js, which doesn't exist inside the file, so I am guessing that it gets imported from somewhere.

It feels like I'm missing something obvious to get this working, is there an easy solution for this?

(Aside: I am aware of the pdf.js smart package, but since I am doing development on Windows it's not really an option for me because I can't get Meteorite. Although I figure that since a smart package already exists, it's quite doable get the two to work together.)

Comment: use the npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdfjs

Answer (score 1):

Meteor shouldn't really complain about the doctype declaration in js files. Is this a built version of pdf.js?

You can technically use atmosphere packages in your project by copying over the files as described in `package.js` and `smart.json` at the repo, in this case at https://github.com/peerlibrary/meteor-pdf.js

i.e add coffeescript & underscore (in `api.use`)

```
meteor add coffeescript underscore
```

Then copy the files over to your `server` dir: (as in `api.add_files`)

```
 bootstrap.coffee
 server.coffee
```

Then you have it installed as if it were put in by meteorite only the files are physically put in, additionally a node module is also required as described at https://github.com/peerlibrary/meteor-pdf.js

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the Jquery getScript and load it externally. I have used this in the template.rendered (enables text selection - if you don't need that you could settle with less):

```
$.getScript( "http://vivin.net/pub/pdfjs/pdf.js" );
$.getScript( "http://vivin.net/pub/pdfjs/textlayerbuilder.js" );
```

Callback function can be given as argument: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/